# What font is used by Unfuddle logo?

Tags: font-identification

I was wondering what font is used by [Unfuddle](https://unfuddle.com/) logo?

[image]

To me it seems to be a customization of an existing font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is **TXT Groovy Smooth** (http://myfonts.us/td-gzlLEW) with some custom modifications in 'u','n' and 'f'.